# How to get longitude and latitude of any address - Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

what is the formulla to get longitude and latitude of any address in Iraq,Iran,.... , if i have alley_name,street_name,State_name,City_name,Country_name in Android?
when I insert an exact address in `TextView` I can't find longitude and latitude,but when I use approximate address it show me approximate address.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html

Comment: Some addresses don't show.

Comment: you can check https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi

Answer (score 0):

This is the method I use to get address from latitude and longitude

```
public static String getAddress(Context context ,String latitude , String longitude)
{

    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addressList;
    StringBuilder addressBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    geocoder = new Geocoder(context,Locale.getDefault());
    try{

        addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(Double.valueOf(latitude),Double.valueOf(longitude),1);
        Address address = addressList.get(0);
        addressBuilder.append(address.getAddressLine(0)).append(",").append(address.getLocality()).append(",")
                .append(address.getAdminArea()).append(",").append(address.getCountryName()).append("||").append(address.getCountryName());

    }catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return addressBuilder.toString();
}
```